# DeleteRecord in ember-data beta

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have created this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faver/60/edit) that illustrates the problem.  If you take these steps:

1. Click on the companies route on the top nav.
2. Click on any of the boxes on the left nav.
3. Click the delete button in the main outlet.

The button invokes this action handler:

```
deleteAll: function(){
  //delete records happens here
  var self = this,
      companiesController = this.controllerFor('companies');
  Ember.run(function(){           
    self.controller.forEach(function(company){
      company.deleteRecord();
      company.save().then(function(c){
      //companiesController.removeObject(c);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Should deleting the record not remove the record from the companiesController's model or how else can I remove this record from the array?

The companiesController model is set in the companiesRoute like this:

```
App.CompaniesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition){
    return this.get('store').find('company', {sector: params.sector});
  },
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get to the bulk actions for a company in your jsbin. I don't see a delete mechanism.